# FormatSelection in select2Option is removing data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

FormatSelection in `select2Option` removing data.

I am receiving my data in

```
$scope.superclasses = superclassDataList.data;
```

where superclassDataList is coming from service in angular.
Data i received from service is :

```
{
"data": [{
    "name": "new Test",
    "id": 4506898162253824,
    "attendanceAllowed": true,
    "subclasses": [{
        "title": "HIN",
        "children": null,
        "entityName": "MyClass",
        "entityId": 5136918324969472
    },
    {
        "title": "ENG 101 A",
        "children": null,
        "entityName": "MyClass",
        "entityId": 5699868278390784
    }]
}
],
"success": true,
"errorMessage": ""
}
```

Code where i am applying my `ng-grid` to show this data:

```
<div ng-show="superclasses[row.rowIndex].edit"><div id="subclasses" ng-model="superclasses[row.rowIndex].subclasses" ui-select2="select2Options" data-placeholder="Add Subclasses" style="width:100%" multiple></div></div>
<div class="ngCellText" ng-class="col.colIndex()" style="display:inline" ng-show="!superclasses[row.rowIndex].edit" ng-repeat="subclass in superclasses[row.rowIndex].subclasses">{{subclass.title}} ,</div>
```

(I added one extra field "edit" in superclasses so don't be confuse with that. If it's true first div(Editable mode) will be visible else second(View mode))

Code for select2 i write is:

```
                $scope.subclassNameFormat="";
                $scope.select2Options = {
                    allowClear : true,
                    multiple: true,
                    width : 550,
                    minimumInputLength: 3,
                    query: function (query){
                        SuperclassService.getSubclassesUnassigned({searchTerm: query.term.toUpperCase()}, function(response) {
                            $scope.classesList = response.data;
                            var data = {
                                results: []
                            };
                            $.each($scope.classesList, function(){
                                if(this.list === undefined || this.list.length === 0) { 
                                    data.results.push({id: this.id, text: this.title,isApplied: false});
                                }
                            });
                            query.callback(data);
                        }, function(error){
                            console.log("Superclass is not deleted.... Please try again");
                        });
                    },
                    formatSelection: function format(state) {
                        if((state.title === undefined || state.title === "") && (state.text !== undefined && state.text !== "")){
                            $scope.subclassNameFormat = state.text;
                        }else if((state.text === undefined || state.text === "") && (state.title !== undefined && state.title !== "") ){
                            $scope.subclassNameFormat = state.title;
                        }
                    }
                };
```

here `getSubclassesUnassigned()` method retrieve data from server on the basis of 3 character i entered to search: (`minimumInputLength: 3`),

Question: The data in `$scope.superclasses` comes from server is complete(JSON Data written above). And for a moment complete data of subclasses visible(when edit is false)  (in this case name of subclasses HIN, ENG 101 A). Once it entered in "`formatSelection`" part of `"$scope.select2Options"` one data from `"subclasses"` array will be remove and it reflect on the `"subclasses"` column in grid (the  code i write above) and show only one name (either "HIN" or "ENG 101 A"). I don't know why it get entered in `"formatSelection"` part of `"select2options"` because till data time `"edit"` field was false. (See in div code `ng-show="!superclasses[row.rowIndex].edit"` ). I don't know how it reflect the data. and even delete the data completely(2nd object of subclasses array.).

Have a same problem when value of div is in editable mode`(ng-show="superclasses[row.rowIndex].edit")` it only show one value of subclasses array.

data after passing control from FormatSelection:

```
   {
"data": [{
    "name": "new Test",
    "id": 4506898162253824,
    "attendanceAllowed": true,
    "subclasses": [{
        "title": "HIN",
        "children": null,
        "entityName": "MyClass",
        "entityId": 5136918324969472
    }]
}],
"success": true,
"errorMessage": ""
   }
```

I tried everything from reading complete doc. about query and formatSelection from select2 but didn't find or understand anything, and also search on stackoverflow but didn't find any relevant link or didn't understand from those already on site. I know it might be silly question for some professionals but i started working on angular just 2 days ago.

Ask me in more explanation is required. I will try to provide everything that i know.

Thanks in advance.

PS: Please ignore My grammatical mistakes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code before "query :" in select2Option

initSelection: function(element, callback) {},

It will initialize your data for select2 which you are receiving in $scope.superclasses. It is working fine for me.